How to select a proper dead time to avoid shoot through events
Are there a general criteria available is selecting a 'bare minimum safe dead time' to avoid shoot through events, when controlling IGBTs or MOSFETs, that are generally used and accepted in the industry?
I have a power module with the below mentioned rise and fall times of the Gate:

Would a dead time of about 175 to 200 ns be sufficient ?
This is how I have come up with the 175 ns number:

Secondly , Some Gate drivers have an inbuilt shoot through protection and interlocking mechanism  built in this way:

In the above case does it still make sense to introduce a dead time from the MCU?

Depends on ratings, requirements, operating mode and application. Do you want a run-down for all cases (a big ask, perhaps -- but maybe someone will volunteer such), or would you be satisfied with a worked example for your particular application (please specify)?

Hi @TimWilliams , A worked example for my application would be a good preferable starting point for me.
